# Solr - if no results, can I set a default response record?

Tags: solr

When there are times where I query my solr core and get 0 results returned, is there a way that I can substitute that for a fallback (default) record to return?

So- for example, instead of getting this (below):

```
<response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">2</int><lst name="params"><str name="indent">on</str><str name="start">0</str><str name="q">asdf</str><str name="version">2.2</str><str name="rows">10</str></lst></lst><result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/></response>
```

I get some kind of return, like the first id in my data set (where field 'id' equals '1')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing out of the box. If you are happy to implement your own Java code, have a look at SearchComponents how they do it. For example, [Query Elevation component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent) does something similar.

In fact, if you don't mind a particular document **always** being returned and - if not needed - ignored by the client, you can use QueryElevationComponent for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to set a default response record that I am aware of. You could just setup this behavior in the client you are using when connecting to Solr. The the `numFound` attribute in the response and then react accordingly.